# Bluetooth still appears on boot list after "disabling" on defconfig on a yocto build

Tags: bluetooth, linux-kernel, yocto, bitbake

I edit my defconfig  on /build/tmp/work/imx6qciu-poky-linux-gnueabi/linux/3.10.53-r0/git/arch/arm/configs with a patch to  set configuration

CONFIG_BT=n
CONFIG_BT_RFCOMM=n
CONFIG_BT_RFCOMM_TTY=n
CONFIG_BT_BNEP=n
CONFIG_BT_BNEP_MC_FILTER=n
CONFIG_BT_BNEP_PROTO_FILTER=n
CONFIG_BT_HIDP=n

but on boot I still get the following messages:

root@imx6qciu:~# modprobe -l | grep bt 
root@imx6qciu:~# modprobe -l | grep blue
root@imx6qciu:~# dmesg | grep Bluetooth
[    0.412731] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.16
[    0.412782] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[    0.412798] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[    0.412813] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[    0.412844] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[    1.538803] Bluetooth: HCI UART driver ver 2.2
[    1.538807] Bluetooth: HCI H4 protocol initialized
[    1.538809] Bluetooth: HCI BCSP protocol initialized
[    1.538812] Bluetooth: HCIATH3K protocol initialized
[    1.538933] Bluetooth: Generic Bluetooth SDIO driver ver 0.1
[    3.738819] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
[    3.738853] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
[    3.738856] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11
[    3.738860] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[    3.738863] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[    3.738872] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[    3.738876] Bluetooth: HIDP (Human Interface Emulation) ver 1.2
[    3.738885] Bluetooth: HIDP socket layer initialized

I also add DISTRO_FEATURES_remove += "bluetooth" to my  local.conf, when I look on the modprobe I can't find any module which is fine, but I still have the messages at boot .... how I can disable the load of those modules.

Answer (score 0):

Either you can disable it from your machine.conf or you can use menuconfig to disable bluetooth from your kernel..
type in your build dir..

```
bitbake -c menuconfig virtual/kernel
```

disable your bluetooth from the kernel and then you can add a recipe to add these changes permanently using fragments e.g.

https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/2.5/kernel-dev/kernel-dev.html#changing-the-configuration

Comment: Thanks Hsn will follow this but I see the changes are similar to what I already did on the defconfig... will update later...

Comment: The problem is that in my custom linux (not developed by me) there are some .patch files and one in specific add board config, so this will overwrite the defconfig I created with this menuconfig, I did "copy" the configuration from the generated file to this patch. Located on:
/home/rs/ciu-imx6q/customboard/sources/meta-customboard/recipes-kernel/linux/linux-customboard-3.10.53/imx6qciu/

the only change was all the BT options are missing except for the line/comment:

# CONFIG_BT is not set

With this it still appears on boot messages

Comment: with the "# CONFIG_BT is not set", it should be disabled from your boot. did you made a fragment.cfg and then added it to a bbappend file? its better to make your own recipe and append the original recipe with your fragment.

Comment: Thanks Hsn, at the end I replace the defconfig with the generated with the menuconfig on the custom recipe, and it make it work. Thanks for your comments